# Каждый элемент массива нужно умножить с каждым элементом этого массива и проверить, является ли квадратный корень этого произведения, целым числом

Tags: java, алгоритм, олимпиада

Каждый элемент массива нужно умножить с каждым элементом этого массива и проверить, является ли квадратный корень этого произведения, целым числом.

Массив состоит из 200000 элементов, каждый элемент содержит число(от 1 до 200000).

Comment: Если нужна помощь с олимпиадной задачей ставьте метку [алгоритм], т.к. проблема часто в подходе, а не в коде. Также обязательно оставляйте ссылку на [задачу](https://acmp.ru/asp/do/index.asp?main=task&id_course=3&id_section=26&id_topic=183&id_problem=1207), чтобы всем было понятно, что она не из какого-нибудь текущего соревнования.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нельзя так просто взять и оптимизировать вложенный цикл. В любом случае он будет выполняться за O(N^2), в данном случае это порядка 4*10^10 итераций, которые никак не уложатся в лимит.

Нужно пересматривать подход к задаче. Минутка математики:

> Имеются два числа a и b. В каких случаях их произведение будет давать полный квадрат?
>   Разложим оба числа на простые множители:
>   a = p<sub>1</sub><sup>k<sub>1</sub></sup>p<sub>2</sub><sup>k<sub>2</sub></sup>...p<sub>N</sub><sup>k<sub>N</sub></sup>
>   b = q<sub>1</sub><sup>l<sub>1</sub></sup>q<sub>2</sub><sup>l<sub>2</sub></sup>...q<sub>M</sub><sup>l<sub>M</sub></sup>
>   Теперь преобразуем числа: множители с четной степенью «выкинем» из произведения, множители с нечетной оставим без степени. Легко показать, что так мы разделим оба числа на полные квадраты, причем на максимально возможные квадраты на которые эти числа делятся.
>   Получим числа x и y:
>   x = p<sub>i<sub>1</sub></sub>p<sub>i<sub>2</sub></sub>...p<sub>i<sub>S</sub></sub>
>   y = q<sub>j<sub>1</sub></sub>q<sub>j<sub>2</sub></sub>...q<sub>j<sub>T</sub></sub>
>   Если `x*y` — полный квадрат, то и `a*b` тоже. А `x*y` будет полным квадратом только если каждый множитель встречается по два раза. А это в свою очередь возможно только если все множители совпадают и `x=y`.
>   Пример: пусть a = 12, b = 108
>   Получаем: a = 2<sup>2</sup>*3, b=2<sup>2</sup>*3<sup>3</sup>
>   x = 3, y = 3
>   Получились одинаковые числа, значит произведение будет полным квадратом.

Отсюда алгоритм:

- Преобразовываем числа в массиве: раскладываем каждое на простые множители, оставляем только множители с нечетной степенью. Это будет работать за O(N*sqrt(M)), где M — максимальное значение числа в массиве.
- Квадраты получатся только по тем парам элементов массива, по которым в результате получились одинаковые значения. Соответственно, для каждого значения в массиве считаем сколько раз оно встречается. O(N).
- Если элемент в массиве встречается `X` раз, то из него можно будет образовать `X*(X-1)/2` пар. Суммируем эти значения для каждого элемента.

Код писать не буду, но алгоритм должен работать быстрее двойного цикла..

Comment: Пардон, не заметил, что ответ с той же сутью уже дан.

Comment: @MBo Да вроде Ваш ответ достаточно сильно отличается от моего. Зря удалили, имхо.

Comment: ОК, может, рассмотрение с немного разных точек зрения будет полезно. "Нормализация" удалением чётных степеней -  хорошая находка, и эффективнее, чем у меня с лишней сущностью